# How can I stay DRY and cohesive when data consumers proliferate?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, static, dry

I have a static class that I use as my "Data Utils" for my project.

This project has several forms and classes, multiple of which make calls to this Data Utils class/the database.

I don't want to violate the DRY principle, so I don't want to have multiple OracleConnection components, one plopped onto each form.

I also don't want to violate cohesion by having my Data Utils class gain "carnal" knowledge of my main form and access it for the OracleConnection.

I *could* create a dynamic OracleConnection inside each Data Utils method, but that, too, would violate DRY.

Is my best solution to convert my static class to non-static, give it an OracleConnection member, and instantiate that in the constructor?

### UPDATE

For future generations, this is what I did, based on LukLed's suggestion:

```
internal class GreatAmericanNovelistsData
{
    private static OracleConnection oc;
    static GreatAmericanNovelistsData()
    {
        oc = new OracleConnection();
        oc.ConnectionString = "User Id=SCLEMENS;Password=HucKfiNn;Server=HANNIBAL;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=0;Direct=True;Sid=HANNIBAL;Service Name=HANNIBAL;";
        oc.Direct = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define static constructor and initialize connection only once. `OracleConnection` object can be static too. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static constructor
    static SimpleClass()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be just the ticket (however, I haven't read the post below yet). Anyway, I'm updating my original post with what I did in accord with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is my best solution to convert my static class to non-static, give it
>   an OracleConnection member, and instantiate that in the constructor?

But that would violate the Dependency Inversion Principal ;)

This sounds somewhat similar to what I had in a recent application, and what I ended up doing was having a factory that returned my OracleConnection instances (I had a factory because I needed to ensure 1 instance per thread, so I was handling that in a factory). The factory implemented an interface, and the various constructors took in an argument that was that interface. A dependency injection framework (like Unity or Ninject) was used to inject the appropriate factory.  This also made it more testable because I could mock out the factory.

So in code, I ended up doing something like (this is off my head so sorry if the syntax is slightly off):

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory
{
  public IDbConnection GetConnection();
}

public class OracleConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
  public IDbConnection GetConnection()
  {
    return new OracleConnection();
  }
}

public class MyAwesomeDataAccess
{
  private IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory;

  public void MyAwesomeDataAccess(IDbConnectionFactory() dbConnectionFactory)
  {
    this.dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
  }

  public SomeData SomeMethod()
  {
    var connection = dbConnectionFactory.GetConnection();
    // do stuff with connection...
  }
}
```

Then in my Unity config I mapped `IDbConnectionFactory -> OracleConnectionFactory`

Of course this might not be the best for everyone in all situations, but I just wanted to give an idea on one possibility. Hope you find a good method that works for you!